# BMPCC + rafcamera arri b to mft + optar 1.2/12mm = vignetting

Tags: video, camera

BMPCC does not support super16 lens?

Example 1.3T - 16T 
[video test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oOxKb_X7tMA)

Comment: I have an old Angénieux zoom on a 16mm Bolex that would vignette quite badly at some zoom/aperture settings, and it was made for 16mm. Maybe it's just the way the lens is?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the setup you described, but does that adapter have some sort of iris control built into it?  I have the adapter pictured below and it doesn't allow the BMPCC to adjust the aperture of the lens, which means I need to use the iris control to adjust the amount of light getting let into the camera.

[image: adapter]

The vignetting is caused by how the iris inside the adapter functions. When you close the iris, to restrict the light entering the camera, it also has the side-effect of creating a vignette.  This is the main reason I stopped using the BMPCC and went back to using the regular BMCC, because I don't have any MFT lenses.

Comment: no, arrib to mft adapter doesn't have IRIS control inside. [photo](http://www.rafcamera.com/media/extendware/ewimageopt/media/inline/61/8/arri-bayonet-arri-b-lens-to-mft-micro-4-3-camera-mount-adapter-514.jpg)

Comment: @SergeyP. thanks for the info.  I'm not sure what the issue is then, sorry!